# Is this really electrolytic capacitor leakage?

Tags: capacitor

I have three vintage power supplies that all show what appears to be electrolytic capacitor leakage. However, after removing two of them from one of the units, I do not see leakage from the bottom of the capacitors so now I'm wondering if this leaky-looking mess is something else.

Here is a overview of the board with the capacitors removed. You can see the two large spots with the brown rings. On this unit only, it also runs and touches two leads of the transistor to the left (TO-220 case).

[image]

Here is the underside of the two capacitors that were removed. The leads look clean so I don't think anything has leaked from there.

[image]

And here is a different angle of one of them showing the metal rim that's generally hidden by the plastic sleeve. It also looks clean.

[image]

The power supply does work. I can't measure the actual capacitance since I don't have a meter in the 4700u range.

Anyone know what this might be?

Comment: Check if there's similar goo underneath the rest of the caps as well. Doesn't look like it from the picture.

Comment: Only the large caps have it... but same on all three power supplies of the same manufacturer & model.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is just glue or adhesive, keeping the large capacitors fixed to the PCB so vibrations and shocks during shipping, handling, and using the device does not cause mechanical damage to the capacitors.

Thr adhesive is specifically applied in a way that is common in application notes for gluing the capacitors. The adhesive does not cover the full circumference, there is a breathing hole left without glue.

Comment: Was wondering about the incomplete circle. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't look like a leak. If it was I'd expect to see some around the mounting TH holes.

Looks more like some sort of glue/adhesive against vibration etc as those caps look relatively larger/taller.

> The power supply does work. I can't measure the actual capacitance since I don't have a meter in the 4700u range.

Note that once the elcos "dry out" the PSU will likely stop working as the dried out capacitors hardly show a capacitance (significant drop or total loss).

Comment: yes it's glue. Just adding a comment that (contrary to popular belief) these things don't often dry out, even after some decades, unless they are situated next to something hot (e.g. a heatsink)

Comment: @danmcb yes but the PSU in the question is described as "vintage" so I assume the capacitors are old enough to experience drying out in the future, also we don't know the construction so still they may...

Comment: I've seen tube gear that is 50+ years old with HV caps in really great condition - if I was rebuilding I would generally replace anyway, but I do get the impression that component quality back then was pretty damn good. It certainly not the case that old electros need to be replaced as a default. Just saying.

Comment: @danmcb There's lots of diverse quality of aluminium electrolytes though. Reputable brands with a high temp spec and life time likely live up to what's promised. Not as likely if you buy some Cheapocon brand from Failexpress...

Comment: @Lundin exactly, which is why pulling out caps just because they are old (that may well have been very carefully sourced and manufactured at the time) and replacing them with a modern component may not always be a good idea.